# iOS - how to handle a case when there is a long text area in an app screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface

I am having a usability issue where in an app screen, there may be too much text and I have nowhere to put that text.

I am attaching a screen shot of my screen. You see how the text on top has more text, but there is no room to put that text. So the text just ends in ....

What is the common way people handle this kind of a situation?

Thanks![image]

Comment: Wrap the text across multiple lines.

Comment: @maddy would I then have to shift all the other page elements down? Or is it possible to add a scroll to the text?

Comment: That's what autolayout or constraints are for. Let everything adjust itself as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redesign your UI so you have more room for that text. Maybe your content will need to scroll. You will need to change that label so that the max number of lines is greater (or 0 for unlimited), and make the frame larger to accomodate more lines. You can also reduce the font size a little to decrease how much extra space you'll need to give it.

If you really wanted to, you could use a `UITextView` for that text, which allows the text to scroll easily (it's a `UIScrollView` subclass). Then you could just scroll that text, though it wouldn't be very good UI and you would still want it to be more than one line, because scrolling when only one line is visible at a time would make it hard to read.

Comment: yes I was thinking to add a scroll. But have never done that yet. Is that configured in the storyboard? How is that done?

Comment: You can add a UITextView either programmatically or in the storyboard, your choice. And if the text within it takes up more than the visible space, it will automatically scroll. Also you'll want to disable the ability to edit it, because a UITextView normally allows editing of text. There's a property on UITextView that will let you disable editing.

Comment: so I should definitely not use UILabel?

Comment: You still could, I just think it would be better to use a UITextView if you want the text to scroll, since it already handles that behavior. You can always embed a UILabel in a UIScrollView if you want, but that might be more complicated. Now if you want all of the content to scroll, not just the text, then you'd want to probably stick with a UILabel and put everything in a UIScrollView.